# Is there a way to import a behavior at a Nao Roboter (Python SDK)

Tags: file, nao-robot

I use the NaoQI SDK for Python.
I also use Choregraphe sometimes but I feel like I can do much more with pure Python code.
Is there a way to load in the Behaviors that are included in the Choregraphe (the dances etc.)? I already found the .xar files for the Behaviors but I have no clue how to load them into my Python code.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to launch behavior or boxes from python code, using ALBehaviorManager or ALFrameManager (a lower level API).

Have a look at these modules' API:
http://doc.aldebaran.com/2-5/naoqi/core/albehaviormanager.html
or also http://ii.tudelft.nl/naodoc/site_en/bluedoc/ALFrameManager.html